# Using different browsers makes my nav bar slightly change?

Tags: html, css

I built my website mostly checking Google chrome to make sure everything was correct. With my nav bar in Google chrome it is perfect, however, when in IE or Fire Fox the dimensions are changed and they do not fit together correctly.

My website is [noahtarr.com](http://noahtarr.com/index.htm)

CSS:

```
nav {   
    margin-top: -1px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

nav a {
    margin-left: -3px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    outline: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    font-family: arial;
    font-weight: bolder;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 21px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #D1DBBD;
    color: #3E606F;

    -webkit-transition: all .9s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;

    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;

    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

}
nav a:hover {
    background-color: #91AA9D;
    color:#193441;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    -o-transition: background-color .3s ease;
    transition: background-color .3s ease;
}
nav a:first-child {
    border-radius: 6px 0 0 0px;
}
nav a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 6px 0px 0;
}
nav a.active {
    color: #193441;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0px 0px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

nav a.adjacent-active-left {
    border-radius: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
}

nav a.adjacent-active-right {
    border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a class="active" href="home.htm">Home</a> 
    <a class="adjacent-active-right" href="about.htm">About</a> 
    <a href="services.htm">Services</a> 
    <a href="portfolio.htm">Portfolio</a> 
    <a href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: That is not surprising. It is a well known fact, that the implementations of different rendering engines deliver slightly different results. That is why you will have to optimize for _all_ browsers, until the result is (more or less) the same. Yes, that is _extremely_ unconvenient, actually an idiotic situation. But that is what comes out if standards are not really implemented in a strict way or if standards are not precise enough. Nothing anyone can do about that situation currently.

Comment: I ended up just changing the nav bar to something more cross browser friendly. Thanks for the help.